# PaxExam exception running tests

Tags: junit, osgi, pax-runner, pax-exam

I am new to Pax Exam and trying to run tests by calling my OSGI service. I am getting following exception when running paxexam test in eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.ServiceLookupException (no     security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:373)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:163)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:225)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy9.remoteCall(Unknown Source)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl$1.invoke(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:112)
at $Proxy10.call(Unknown Source)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.call(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:287)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.container.remote.RBCRemoteTarget.call(RBCRemoteTarget.java:70)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.container.def.internal.PaxRunnerTestContainer.call(PaxRunnerTestContainer.java:187)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactor.invoke(AllConfinedStagedReactor.java:74)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner$2.evaluate(JUnit4TestRunner.java:284)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any ideas why this could happen? This happens when I have the @Inject DataGenerator line enabled in the following code.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4TestRunner.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory.class)
public class SampleTest{

    @Inject
    private DataGenerator dataService;

    @Inject
    private BundleContext bundleContext;
```

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Looks like you are missing the dependency to swissbox. Can you give some more details about the pax exam version you use and the exact setup. Perhaps you can upload an example project to github or similar.

Comment: See also: https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXEXAM-493

Answer (score 0):

As per [PAXEXAM-493](https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXEXAM-493), the underlying cause of the Exception is that your `DataGenerator` service is not found by the container. However, normally Pax Exam would report this service failure lookup "nicely". In this case, when Pax Exam tries to load the class `ServiceLookupException` in order to do that, the class lookup of the `ServiceLookupException` itself fails (for some reason not yet identified by the Pax developers).